# Most efficient way to select record if a value has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

What would be the most efficient way to select a record when one of the value has changed? 
Ex:

I have an account history table like below where records are being created when the account change:

```
Id  AcctNb Active Created
8   123456 1      01/03/2012
6   123456 0      01/01/2012
```

I like to find an efficient way to return the record where the active status has changed since the last entry.

**UPDATE**

The query I am using at the moment which works but inefficiently"

```
select d1.acctNb,d1.active, d2.active 
from d044 d1 , d044 d2 
where d1.created = '2012-04-14'
and d1.acctNb = d2.acctNb 
and d2.created = (select max(d.created) from d044 d where d.acctNb = d2.acctNb and d.id != d1.id)   
and (d1.active != d2.active)
```

Comment: So far I have an sql query which works but take over a minute to run even with index optimisation.

Comment: What database, Postgresql, MySQL, SQL Server, etc? Some query solutions can be solved only by applying a specific feature of the database

Comment: For a single account, do you want only the *latest* `Active` change or *all* the changes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create table log
(
  log_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  acct_id int not null,
  active bit not null,
  created datetime not null
);


insert into log(acct_id, active,created)
values
(1,1,'January 1, 2012'),
(1,1,'January 2, 2012'),
(1,0,'January 3, 2012'),
(1,0,'January 4, 2012'),
(1,1,'January 5, 2012'),
(2,0,'February 1, 2012'),
(2,1,'February 2, 2012'),
(2,0,'February 3, 2012'),
(2,1,'February 4, 2012'),
(2,1,'February 5, 2012');
```

The solution:

```
with serialize as
(
  select row_number() 
  over(partition by acct_id order by created) rx,
  *
  from log
)
select ds.acct_id, 
ds.active ds_active, 
pr.active pr_active,

ds.created

from serialize ds -- detect second row
join serialize pr -- previous row
on pr.acct_id = ds.acct_id
and ds.rx = pr.rx + 1

where ds.rx >= 2 and
pr.active <> ds.active
```

Query output: January 3, January 5, February 2, February 3, February 4

Those are the dates when changes on active had occurred(detected)

Basically the logic is, starting from second row, we scan its previous row, if their active's value didn't match (via `WHERE pr.active <> ds.active`), we show them on results

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68136/4

Comment: Woah, that sql looks like it comes from another planet. I will give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

2 ways

1)
add a column

update_tsmp timestamp

put a trigger on the table that runs after update or insert
-- checks the Active field
-- if it has changed update update_tsmp to the current timestamp

now you must define "since the last entry" to determine whether you want to return the record

2)
create a history table

Id  AcctNb Active Created change_tsmp updating_user delete_flag

put a trigger on the table that runs **before** update or delete
-- copies the record to the history table, checking the delete flag as appropriate

Comment: The table records are taken from a daily report and is already a history table. Every day I will have or not an entry with the new account statuses. Hence the records are never updated but always inserted.

Comment: index the created field, or better, if it's lot and lots of records partition the table on the created field

Answer (score 0):

If future SQL Server will have LAG windowing function, you can simplify the comparison of previous row to current by using LAG

This works now on Postgresql(since 8.4), it already has LAG and LEAD windowing function:

```
create table log
(
  log_id serial primary key,
  acct_id int not null,
  active boolean not null,
  created timestamp not null
);


insert into log(acct_id, active,created)
values
(1,true,'January 1, 2012'),
(1,true,'January 2, 2012'),
(1,false,'January 3, 2012'),
(1,false,'January 4, 2012'),
(1,true,'January 5, 2012'),
(2,false,'February 1, 2012'),
(2,true,'February 2, 2012'),
(2,false,'February 3, 2012'),
(2,true,'February 4, 2012'),
(2,true,'February 5, 2012');
```

LAG approach is elegantly simpler than [ROW_NUMBER and JOIN combo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10171519/11432) approach:

```
with merge_prev as
(
    select     
        acct_id, created, 

        lag(active) over(partition by acct_id order by created) pr_active, -- previous row's active
        active sr_active -- second row's active

    from log
) 

select * 
from merge_prev
where 
    pr_active <> sr_active
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b1eb0/25

**EDIT**

LAG is already available on SQL Server 2012: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d17c0/1